# Syntax error on join operation access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to do some join operations in sql access but I keep on getting the **join** operation error. At first it was just the JOIN alone, but then I realized I had to add the INNER which I did but it didn't resolve the error.

Code below:

```
SELECT Formula.*, Ingred.[Europe Ban] 
FROM [Ingred]  
INNER JOIN Ingred ON Formula.[Ingredient] = Ingred.Ingredients;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, you want `Formula` in the `FROM` clause, not `Ingred` twice:

```
SELECT Formula.*, Ingred.[Europe Ban]
FROM Formula INNER JOIN
     Ingred
     ON Formula.[Ingredient] = Ingred.Ingredients;
```

Comment: that solved the issue but now im getting 
cannot join memo ole or hyperlink object Formula.ingredient = Ingred.Ingredients my relationships should be correct

Comment: You can't JOIN on Memo (Long Text) fields, and if you are trying, your table design is most probably wrong. @mark7328